# Iterating over vector of list of pairs giving errors

Tags: c++11, dijkstra

I have written the following code but there is something wrong in it. It shows no compiler errors but i get a run failed. I am unable to figure out where the logic went wrong.

The code is for dijkstras algorithm to find the shortest path for every vertex.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
# define inf 0x3f3f3f3f
typedef pair<int,int> ipair;

class graph
{
    int v;
    vector<list<pair<int,int>>> adj; 
public:
    graph(int v);
    void addedge(int w,int u,int v);
    void shortestpath(int src);
};

graph::graph(int v)
{
    this->v=v;
}

void graph::addedge(int u,int v,int w)
{
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v,w));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u,w));
}

void graph::shortestpath(int src)
{
    priority_queue<ipair,vector<ipair>,greater<ipair>> pq; 

    vector<int> dist(v,inf);
    pq.push(make_pair(0,src));
    dist[src]=0;

    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        int m=pq.top().second;
        pq.pop();

        for(pair<int,int>& i:adj[m]) //check this ranged based for loop
        {          

                int p=i.first;
                int pwt=i.second;

                if(dist[p]>dist[m]+pwt)
                {
                dist[p]=dist[m]+pwt;
                pq.push(make_pair(dist[p],p));
                }

        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<v;++i)
        cout << i << " " << dist[i];

}

int main()
{    
    graph g1(9);
    g1.addedge(0,1,4);
    g1.addedge(0,7,8);
    g1.addedge(1,2,8);
    g1.addedge(1,7,11);
    g1.addedge(2,3,7);
    g1.addedge(2,8,2);
    g1.addedge(2,5,4);
    g1.addedge(3,4,9);
    g1.addedge(3,5,14);
    g1.addedge(4,5,10);
    g1.addedge(5,6,2);
    g1.addedge(6,7,1);
    g1.addedge(6,8,6);
    g1.addedge(7,8,7);
    g1.shortestpath(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Where I think the logic went wrong:
As you can see i thought of creating a vector> adj, instead of allocating space for adj.so is this somehow wrong or correct?. If this is correct then maybe check the range based for loop i used in void shortest path(i have marked it with a comment),maybe something is wrong in that loop?.
Can somebody please help me out?. I am stuck.

Comment: "i get a run failed" is not a sufficient description of what went wrong when you ran it.

Comment: it just says run failed but build successful. I got nothing more. No compiling errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v,w));
```

in `graph::addedge` element `adj[u]` doesn't exist, and program crashes. You got undefined behavior reading element of vector out of range.
You should create `v` elements of this vector in constructor of `graph`.

```
graph::graph(int v)
{
    this->v=v;
    adj.resize(v);   // <---
}
```

Algorithm looks fine, result is correct, but printed output is not readable. You should add endl in your for loop to get more readable result.

```
for(int i=0;i<v;++i)
    cout << i << " " << dist[i] << endl;
```